# Как сериализовать Int из XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, сериализация

Как из этой строки достать просто Int32, пользуясь `System.Xml...`?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<int>2004</int>
```

---

Этот код не работает:

```
using (var sr = new StringReader(mystr))
{
    return (Int32)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Int32)).Deserialize(sr);
}
```

Comment: _не работает_ - проверил, работает. Что именно у вас происходит? Какая ошибка?

Answer (score 4):

`XmlSerializer` — слишком тяжеловесный способ для такой задачи.

Используйте Linq to Xml.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Код:

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(sr);
int n = (int)xElement;
```